# Ability to update collections on front-end in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm struggling to get my head around the ability to edit *any* collection that's available to the front-end, and how to prevent it - and if this is a feature only available to Mongol.

Mongol states:

> … because Mongol is a debugOnly package, it does not compile to production code.

Which is great, but as I'm new to Meteor I'm not sure if Mongol is just an interface in this scenario, or if the ability to `update` is something always available to the front-end (and Mongol is just making it easier).

My scenario is that I have a form submission page that grabs the profile of an associated `Meteor.user` to display their name along with the form:

**HTML**

```
<template name="form">
  <h2>Submission for: {{ user.profile.name }}</h2>
  <form id="brief">
    …
  </form>
</template>
```

**Route**

```
Router.route('/form/:_id', {

  loadingTemplate: 'loading',

  waitOn: function () {
    return Meteor.subscribe('forms', this.params._id);
  },

  action: function () {
    this.render('form', {
      data: {
        _id: this.params._id,
        form: function() {
          return Forms.findOne({});
        },
        user: function() {
          return Meteor.users.findOne({});
        }
      }
    });
  }

});
```

**Publication**

```
Meteor.publishComposite('forms', function(formId) {
  return {
    find: function() {
      return Forms.find({_id: formId});
    },
    children: [
      {
        find: function(form) {
          return Meteor.users.find({_id: form.userId}, {fields: {profile:1}});
        }
      }
    ]
  };
});
```

This works perfectly - however using the Mongol console I can `update`, `duplicate` and `remove` the user. Naturally in a production environment I wouldn't want this to be possible - is this something only available because Mongol is there, or could a determined user achieve the same thing without Mongol?

If they *can*, how do I prevent/work with it?

**Edit:** It's also elaborated on here: https://github.com/msavin/Mongol/blob/master/documentation/SECURITY.md

Given how they refer to 'special methods' I'm assuming that's what allows this to happen, and that the ability to directly update the fields isn't ordinarily available to the front-end. If anyone's able to confirm that would be ace!

Comment: Yes, AFAIK `mongol` uses those `special methods` to update the records. I think this is what happens in `mongol` from my understanding. When you click on update mongol reads the collection name, record details and all the other values and calls server side method. Server side method will take those params and will update the docs.

Comment: Since it is a `debugOnly` package you don't need to worry about production environment untill unless you have strong `allow/deny` rules

Comment: atleast that is what I get from the source https://github.com/msavin/Mongol/blob/master/server/methods.js#L59

Comment: Ha, I just got caught out by this too, thinking I'd created a terribly insecure app :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Mongol uses a backdoor solution (in debug/dev only) to access and change your mongo docs in the db. This means it wont be included in your production code. As far as client side operations on the DB, Meteor restricts updating, removing, and inserting to the server although you can use Meteor's allow/deny rules to allow the client to update a DB collection. However, allow/deny rules need to be very tight to ensure the client can not alter data they should not be able to. For this reason, most people stick to using server side DB changes that are fired by meteor.methods that the client can initialize.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a debugOnly package  as long as you don't deploy to production  in "debug mode" it is safe.

Comment: I suppose my question could be more easily summarised as, 'are the abilities Mongol uses available without Mongol' - as I do appreciate that Mongol isn't loaded into the production environment.

Comment: no it is not available unless you made available it from server side